# React not re-rendering DOM after this.forceUpdate() or this.setState(this.state)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm having an issue re-rendering the DOM after something has been spliced from an array in my state variable. Here is the code for this component:

```
class AddMusicResource extends Component {


removeFile(file, event) {
    var filesPreview = this.state.filesPreview
    var filesToBeSent = this.state.filesToBeSent
    var i = filesToBeSent.indexOf(file)
    console.log(i)
    if(i !== -1) {
        filesToBeSent.splice(i, 1)
        filesPreview.splice(i, 1)
    }
    this.setState({filesToBeSent, filesPreview});   
    this.setState(this.state)

}

onDrop(acceptedFiles, rejectedFiles) {
  var filesToBeSent=this.state.filesToBeSent;
  for(var file in acceptedFiles) {
    console.log('Accepted files: ', acceptedFiles[file].name);
    filesToBeSent.push(acceptedFiles[file]);
  }

    var filesPreview=[];
    for(var i in filesToBeSent){
      filesPreview.push(
        <div key={i}>
            {filesToBeSent[i].name}
            <IconButton
                  iconClassName="material-icons"
                  onClick={this.removeFile.bind(this, filesToBeSent[i])}
                >
                  close
            </IconButton>
        </div>
      )
    }
    this.setState({filesToBeSent, filesPreview});
}

render() {
    return (
    <Card shadow={0} style={{ margin: '10px'}}>
        <CardTitle>Add Music Resources</CardTitle>
        <CardText >
           <form id="upload-form">              
                <Dropzone 
                    onDrop={(files) => this.onDrop(files)}
                    multiple={true}
                >
                    <div>Try dropping some files here, or click to select files to upload.</div>
                </Dropzone>
                <div>
                     Files to be uploaded are:
                     {this.state.filesPreview}
                </div>

                <input className={this.state.buttonClasses} type="submit" value="Submit" />
            </form>
        </CardText>
    </Card>
    );
}
}

export default AddMusicResource;
```

So basically I'm taking a file input and then pushing the name of the file to a filePreview array that is being rendered on the page, but when a user clicks the close x to the right of the name I expect that the name of the file would be removed from the DOM. The `removeFile()` is working as intended and is indeed removing the correct element from the page, but the only time that the DOM would update to see that file as removed is if I added another file using the Dropzone.

I was wondering if anyone could help me figure out why the DOM is not rerendering at the end of my `removeFile()` function?

I have tried both `this.setState(this.state)` and `this.forceUpdate()` but neither have been successful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mutating the state and React has a hard time to find what actually changed. Try this instead:

```
removeFile(file, event) {
    var i = this.state.filesToBeSent.indexOf(file);

    if (i < 0)
        return;

    this.setState((prevState) => {
        return {
            filesToBeSent: prevState.filesToBeSent.filter((element, index) => index !== i),
            filesPreview: prevState.filesPreview.filter((element, index) => index !== i)
        };
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, what is the difference between this code your provided and what I was doing?

Comment: I'm glad that I could help you. So, the difference is that React performs a shallow comparison to determine that a re-render is necessary. In your code you are mutating the filesToBeSent and filesPreview arrays directly, so the old array and the array with the changes have the same reference, therefore React thinks the content has not changed. In the code I provided, I am actually setting an entire new array into the state. This way, React checks that the reference of the old array is different than the new array, so it issues a re-render.

Comment: Notice that I use the array method filter to set the new state. The filter method creates a new array with the elements that pass the condition provided.